# solr to gsa (google search appliance)

Tags: solr, lucene, google-search-appliance

I have 100s of websites that rely on a google appliance that I'd like to replace with solr.  I can manage the crawling, indexing, etc. on solr, but I'd really love to avoid changing the code in all those websites.  I'd like to find an existing wrapper that looks like a gsa, but uses solr under the hood.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a link, rather than a more general answer. If you did want a more general answer, you may want to explain what the existing websites have now that you want SOLR to notice/identify without changing. And you might be better off looking at Nutch rather than Solr as the area to search around, as I suspect all those GSA parameters would be processed before they hit Solr.

Comment: Again, I'm not asking how to use solr, how to crawl, nutch, etc. hence, "I can manage the crawling, indexing, etc. on solr"  I am asking if there is an existing solution (webservice) that looks like a GSA to its consumer, but uses solr under the hood.  In this way, the sites that are currently using the GSA to render the search results page wouldn't need to change... they'd just point to this new webservice (that is a GSA front for a Solr backend) and relate to it just like it were a google search appliance.